# How to approximate this bell-shaped integral function using Mathematica?

Tags: functions, series-expansion, approximation

Consider the following function :
$$\tag{1}
f(v) = v^{\frac{d}{2}} \int_v^{\infty} u^{a \,-\, \smash{\frac{d}{2}} \,-\, 1} \; e^{-\, a \, u} \; du,
$$
where $a$ and $d$ are two positive constants (parameters).  Notice the lower limit of the integral : $v$ is a variable with the constaint $v \ge 0$.  In *Mathematica*, the plot of this function (for $0 \le v < \infty$) shows a bell-shaped curve.  I'm giving the *Mathematica* code here to show it :

```
function[v_, a_, d_] := v^(d/2)NIntegrate[u^(a - d/2 - 1)Exp[- a u], {u, v, Infinity}]

Plot[{
    function[v, 1/4, 2],
    function[v, 1/2, 3],
    function[v, 1, 4]
    }, {v, 0, 10},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotStyle -> {
        Directive[Blue, Thick],
        Directive[Red, Thick],
        Directive[Orange, Thick]
    }
]
```

Now, I would like to define an approximation of this function around the maximal value $f_{\text{max}} = f(v_0)$ (for an unknown $v_0$), since I can't get an explicit expression from the integral.  I guess the approximation should look like some Gauss-like function, but I'm not sure.

What is the best approximation of function (1) around its maximal value ?  How to find it using *Mathematica* ?

**EDIT :**  What I'm looking for is an explicit analytical function of all variables ; $v$, $a$, $d$.  Not numerical evaluation.  Something that may look like this :
$$\tag{2}
f(v) \approx A(a, d) \, v^{B(a, d)} \, e^{-\, (v \,-\, C(a, d))^2/D(a, d)},
$$
or a Taylor expansion around the maximal value of the function :
$$\tag{3}
f(v) \approx A(a, d) + B(a, d)(v - C(a, d)) + \frac{1}{2} \, D(a, d)(v - C(a, d))^2,
$$
where $A(a, d)$, $B(a, d)$, $C(a, d)$ and $D(a, d)$ are analytical functions of $a$ and $d$.  I'm especially interested in the function $C(a, d)$ (position of the max value of the $f$ function).

Take note that the derivative of function (1), set to 0, give this relation :
$$\tag{4}
f_{\text{max}} = \frac{2}{d} \; v_0^a \; e^{-\, a \, v_0},
$$
where $v_0 \equiv v_0(a, d)$ is the position of the max value of (1).

Comment: I realized that my question wasn't specifying clearly that I was looking for a function of *all* variables ; *v*, *a* and *d*.  Sorry.  Please, see the edit.

Comment: The coefficient $B(a,d)=0$ in $(3)$ up to the Fermat theorem.

Comment: @user64494, ah !  Yes, of course !  Since it's an approximation around the max value (in the case of the Taylor expansion).  But not in the case of the gaussian approximation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but here is my best guess. There does appears to be a closed form expression for your function. In particular,

```
v^(d/2)Integrate[u^(a-d/2-1)Exp[-a u],{u,v,Infinity},Assumptions->Re[v]>0&&Re[a]>0]
```

Evaluates to

```
a^(1/2 (-2 a + d)) v^(d/2) Gamma[a - d/2, a v]
```

Finding the maximum is as simple as differentiating and setting the expression equal to zero. Writing a function

```
D[a^(1/2 (-2 a+d)) v^(d/2) Gamma[a-d/2,a v],v]
(*-a^(1+1/2 (-2 a+d)) E^(-a v) v^(d/2) (a v)^(-1+a-d/2)
+1/2 a^(1/2 (-2 a+d)) d v^(-1+d/2) Gamma[a-d/2,a v]*) 

maxvalue[a_?NumberQ,d_?NumberQ]:=
Re@FindRoot[-a^(1+1/2 (-2 a+d)) E^(-a v) v^(d/2) (a v)^(-1+a-d/2)
+1/2 a^(1/2 (-2 a+d)) d v^(-1+d/2) Gamma[a-d/2,a v]==0,{v,.1}][[1,2]]
```

Evaluating `maxvalue` gives the value $v$ for which $f\left(v,a,d\right)$ is maximized. It is also easy to calculate the corresponding maximum value of $f\left(v,a,d\right)$. For example,

```
maxvalue[1/4, 2]
(*0.321069*)

function[maxvalue[1/4, 2], 1/4, 2]
(*0.694688*)
```

---

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could solve the problem numerically if a closed form solution to the integral does not exist. In this case I used `ND` from the `NumericalCalculus` package.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
maxvaluenum[a_?NumberQ,d_?NumberQ]:=FindRoot[ND[function[v,a,d],v,k]==0,{k,.1}][[1,2]]
maxvaluenum[1/4, 2]
(*0.321067*)
```

This gives roughly the same result as before. I should note that this method is a lot more computationally intensive then the direct method.

---

**EDIT 2**

Here is my attempt at what I think you are trying to get at. The general idea is to determine the best fitting polynomial through some range near the neighborhood of the maximum value of $f$. Here we make a new function

```
approxfun[orderin_,ain_,din_,rangein_]:=
Module[{order=orderin,a=ain,d=din,range=rangein},
maxval=maxvalue[a,d];
data=Table[{v,Re[a^(1/2 (-2 a+d)) v^(d/2) Gamma[a-d/2,a v]]},
{v,maxval-range,maxval+range,range/(10*order)}];
lm=LinearModelFit[data,Evaluate[Table[x^i,{i,1,order}]],x];
Clear[data];
lm];
```

Using this function creates a `FittedModel` of a specified order through the given range around the function's maximum value. Example usage:

```
approxfun[4, 1/4, 2, .1]
(*FittedModel[0.550941 +1.27435 x-4.10958 x^2+5.8875 x^3-3.44731 x^4]*)
```

You can see that we have created a best fit polynomial function of order 4 with $v \in v_{f_{max}} \pm range$.  Plotting with respect to $f$

[image]

You can also directly use `Series`

```
Plot[Evaluate[Normal@Series[a^(1/2 (-2 a + d)) v^(d/2) Gamma[a - d/2, a v],
{v, maxvalue[a, d], 4}] /. {a -> 1/4, d -> 2}], 
{v, Evaluate[maxvalue[a, d] /. {a -> 1/4, d -> 2}] - .1, 
Evaluate[maxvalue[a, d] /. {a -> 1/4, d -> 2}] + .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get an analytical expression for the maxvalue of the function and its argument ?  I'm not looking for numerical evaluations.  What I'm looking for is an expression like $$f(v) \approx \text{some simple and regular function of $v$},$$ around the max value.

Comment: @Cham There's no definite answer to that. You could use, e.g. `Series` around the maximum, or sample the function and use `Interpolation`, or fit a parabola near the maximum... (The locations of the maximum are easily found with Marchi's solution.) We can help you with implementation of the method you choose, but "what is the **best** approximation of function (1)" is ambiguous, and most likely beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @corey979, I'm looking for a simple ***analytical*** approximation (no numerical evaluations).  A Taylor serie would do (around the max value), but a gaussian would probably be better.  Since the question may be ambiguous, many answers are allowed.

Comment: @corey979 Beat me to the punch while working on updating my answer. I was thinking along the same lines, now seeing your answer, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Taking `function` from the OP

```
function[v_, a_, d_] := 
 v^(d/2) NIntegrate[u^(a - d/2 - 1) Exp[-a u], {u, v, Infinity}]
```

and `maxvalue` from [Marchi's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130463/22013)

```
maxvalue[a_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := 
 Re@FindRoot[-a^(1 + 1/2 (-2 a + d)) E^(-a v) v^(d/2) (a v)^(-1 + a - 
          d/2) + 1/2 a^(1/2 (-2 a + d)) d v^(-1 + d/2) Gamma[a - d/2, 
        a v] == 0, {v, .1}][[1, 2]]
```

for some parameters

```
{a, d} = {5/7, 2.4};
```

I find the max value

```
max = maxvalue[a, d]
```

> 0.453786

Then I sample the function near the maximum:

```
data = Table[{x, function[x, a, d]}, {x, max - 1/10 max, max + 1/10 max, 1/100 max}];

plot1 = ListPlot @ data;
```

and fit a parabola

```
nlm = Normal @ NonlinearModelFit[data, A x^2 + B x + c, {A, B, c}, x]
```

> 0.261741 + 0.356048 x - 0.391348 x^2

Verification:

```
Maximize[nlm, x]
```

> {0.342724, {x -> 0.4549}}

```
plot2 = Plot[nlm, {x, max - 1/10 max, max + 1/10 max}, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

Visually the approximation is very satisfying:

```
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

One can try with different functions (maybe a Gaussian curve), different
range of the region to approximate in, etc.

Comment: This is still numerical.  I strongly suspect (I may be wrong !) that we could find an analytical function with parameters (i.e. symbolic function) : $$f(v) \approx g(v, a, d),$$ where the *g* function is a gaussian or a polynomial.

Comment: Please, see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach by making use of  [the PadeApproximant](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant.html) around the same point $v=0.5$ for each $d \in [1,4]$ and each $a \in [1/4,2]$.
One does not need to find any extrema of the function under consideration.

```
function[v_, a_, d_] :=  v^((1/2)*d)*NIntegrate[u^(a - (1/2)*d - 1)*Exp[-a*u], {u, v, Infinity},Method -> "DoubleExponential"];

a=PadeApproximant[function[v, 1/4, 2], {v, 0.5, {3, 3}}]
```

> (0.681942 + 1.88855 (-0.5 + v) + 1.06914 (-0.5 + v)^2 - 
>    0.1788 (-0.5 + v)^3)/(1.00000000000000 + 2.94577 (-0.5 + v) + 
>    2.35946 (-0.5 + v)^2 + 0.433973 (-0.5 + v)^3)

```
Plot[{a, function[v, 1/4, 2]}, {v, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to make a precision about what I'm looking for.  I hope it's clearer.